# Unknow column in field list

Tags: sql, mysql

Im trying to run this query but got the error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '500001 ' in 'field list'

which is weird because obviously 500001 is not stated at field list, can anybody help me how to resolve, thank you very much

```
`select usr.login, usr.name, usr.group,
usr.equity,LEVERAGE,
CASE WHEN usr.EQUITY < 10000 then 500
WHEN usr.EQUITY between 10001 and 50000 then 400
WHEN usr.EQUITY between 50001 and 100000 then 300
WHEN usr.EQUITY between 100001 and 250000 then 200
WHEN usr.EQUITY between 250001 and 500000 then 100
WHEN usr.EQUITY > 500001 then 50
ELSE 1
END AS MAXLEVARGE,
CASE WHEN usr.EQUITY between 10001 and 50000 and LEVERAGE > 400 then 'DROP TO 400'
WHEN usr.EQUITY between 50001 and 100000 and LEVERAGE > 300 then 'DROP TO 300'
WHEN usr.EQUITY between 100001 and 250000 and LEVERAGE > 200 then 'DROP TO 200'
WHEN usr.EQUITY between 250001 and 500000 and LEVERAGE > 100 then 'DROP TO 100'
WHEN usr.EQUITY > 500001  and LEVERAGE > 50 then 'DROP TO 50'
ELSE 'NORMAL'
END AS ACTION,
usr.agent_account,team
from aaa.USERS usr
inner join aaa.ibheirachytemp ib on ib.login=usr.AGENT_ACCOUNT
where usr.group not like '%p5%'
and usr.group not like '%test%'
and equity > 10000
group by usr.login;`
```

i have tried many ways but the query is not running

Comment: Try commenting out all in the columns in the SELECT list and then add them back in one by one, running the query each time. When you get the error then you'll know which column is causing the issue. Assuming it is one of the case statements, simplify that statement to a single WHEN and, assuming that doesn't error, add in the other WHEN clauses one by one until it errors. That should allow you to pinpoint where the issue is

Comment: Why is your query contained within backticks?